# meta_query weird behaviour, static int will work, but not user data

Tags: wp-query, custom-field, filters, meta-query

I am currently trying to build a Ajax filter for a CPT, all the products have a min and max value of a specific range in which the products works best. Therefore i created ACF groups with a min and max value as a number field.

When i am trying to add the meta_query with the static values listed below, i am able to find the corresponding product, however when i replace the 1,200 with the $min and $max (they are for sure integers) the query returns 0 products and doesn't find the product.

I have no idea how this is possible, as i am feeding the exact same type to the query. Any idea what can cause this issue?

```
foreach ($filter_data as $data ) {

    $stripped_id = str_replace('slider-', '', $data['id']);
    $stripped_id = str_replace('-range', '', $stripped_id);   

    $min = intval($data['min']);
    $max = intval($data['max']);

    array_push( $metaquery, array(
        'key'       => 'ultimate-torque_min',
        'value'     => array( 1, 200 ),
        'compare'   => 'BETWEEN',
        'type'      => 'NUMERIC'
    ));

    array_push( $metaquery, array(
        'key'       => 'ultimate-torque_max',
        'value'     => array( 1, 200 ),
        'compare'   => 'BETWEEN',
        'type'      => 'NUMERIC'
    ));

}
```

Comment: It the query works for hard-coded numbers, there is no reason it should not work when those numbers are swapped for variables containing numbers. Have you dumped `$min` and `$max` just prior to constructing the metaquery to ensure they are the correct values?

Comment: @bosco that was exactly my thought, i have var dumped the values and they are indeed integers. After the meta array is pushed and dump it, the values are exactly the same as the static ones.

Comment: I can't think of any reason the behavior would be different then... Just to be sure, you're adding them in the form `'value' => array( $min, $max ),`? And you've verified that they're the same numbers as the test code - `1` and `200`, respectively?

Comment: I guess it's also a bit strange that this is in a loop - if `$filter_data` has multiple items, you'll end up with `n` metaquery entries for `ultimate-torque_min` and `ultimate-torque_max` which might result in bizarre behaviors

Comment: @bosco I am also a bit stunned by this, i have var dumped every step to make sure the correct type is used. The loop is because i have 5 different sliders, i was just putting the static torque field for testing. Thanks for your help, gonna dive into it deeper tomorrow.